# How can I made my condition working in Odoo

Tags: odoo

```
    <div width="100%" class="font_fam" style="text-align:right; margin-top:-0px">
        <font style="font-size: 18px;">
            <t t-if="'o.date' &gt; '20/04/2023'">
              <span t-field="o.date"/>
              <span>Test</span>
            </t>
        </font>
    </div>
```

first I think o.date didn't work so I just try to span o.date but it still working why my condition didn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6eXS.png)

this is o.date value when I span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `o.date` instead of `'o.date'`. `o.date` is probably a date object and can't be compared to a string `'20-04-2023'`:

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

Try to convert the date string to a date object:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('20/04/2023', '%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

Comment: It will working thank to much :))))